# how to remove the scroll bar/stick indicator?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-view

How to remove/hide the scroll bar indicator (vertical stick that's shown when scrolling) in `ionic 3`

I have tried: not sure what the below code does

```
.scroll-content {
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

::-webkit-scrollbar is only available in WebKit-based browsers (e.g., Google Chrome).

Comment: thank you..it's working on web, not tested on device yet, I will mark after i test on device. so this won't work on IOS ?